# How to incorporate existing make file with Android NDK

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, makefile

So I have a huge existing C project that I have placed in `$PROJECT/jni` directory. This project is normally made by running a configure script which creates the Makefiles which then allows the project to be compiled via `make`.

This project is rather large and has many directories containing source files and header files.

I guess I am missing a fundamental understanding here of how `Android.mk` is supposed to work. Is it supposed to replace the configure and makefile that is currently used to compile the project? Or would I be incorporating the generated makefile from my configure script into the `Android.mk`? The examples they provide are rather trivial with only a few source files. My `jni` directory looks more like:

```
jni/
  folder1/subfolder1
  folder1/subfolder2
  folder1/source
  folder2/source
  .....
  foldern/source
  configure/
  configure/configure.sh
  Makefile
  Android.mk
```

The generated makefiles are pretty extensive (good amount of configuration and there is one in every directory) so I am little lost as to how to approach this.

EDIT:

The major issue is that the examples that ship with the NDK are trivial examples. They have 3-5 source files in the top level jni directory. My issue is that this is a huge project with complex configuration with 4 top level folders each with many subdirectories. I cannot simply move the source into the jni folder and run the ndk compiler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To answer your question, yes `Android.mk` *is* the Android build system.  Google barely mentions that the "language" of this file is implemented as GNU make macros.  The docs want you to describe your project in terms of those macros.  They handle all the grungy cross-compilation details.  I'm pretty sure Google has taken this approach to improve forward portability of `Android.mk` files as the development tools evolve.

The upshot is that (and I know you won't want to hear this) the best answer is probably to write a proper NDK  `Android.mk` for your big project from scratch.

[This article](http://warpedtimes.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/building-open-source-libraries-with-android-ndk/) lays out the same observations I made porting a library of about 800 files and 300k SLOC.  Unfortunately I burned almost two weeks reaching the same conclusion: Cross-compilation causes at least some `configure` scripts to fail (result in erroneous `config.h` files).  I "invented" pretty much the same techniques he's using in the article.  But  even after I got a clean build, the resulting static library did not work fully. Hours of debugging netted no useful information.  [Caveat: I am no kind of config tools expert. A guru probably would have spotted my error.  So it goes.] It took me a couple of days to create a clean `Android.mk`.  The resulting library ran all tests first time through.  And it has ported cleanly through several revs of development tools.

Unfortunately building a library that uses `configure` without the auto tools means building your own `config.h` by hand for the target environment.  This might not be as bad as it sounds. IME systems tend to define much more in their `configure` environments than they actually use.  Getting a clear idea of real dependencies may repay the tedious effort during future refactoring.

The summary statement from the article says it all:

> Autotool is good only on GNU systems and using it for cross compiling can be really tedious, confusing, error prone or even impossible. The method described here is a hack and should be used at your own risk.

Sorry I don't have a more positive suggestion.

Comment: I completely agree with your observation. The generation of `config.h` from the `config.h.in` is impossible in a cross-compile environment. However, running the configure natively `might possibly` work, but that's a whole other beast :).

Answer (score 5):

My answer works best in tandem with [Gene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161878/gene)'s answer.

`./configure`'s creation of the config file is based on compiling (and possibly running) small snippets of `C` code for each test. The success of each test sets a corresponding variable in the `config.h.in` template to create the `config.h`. The compile-only tests can be successfully tested in a cross-compile environment. However, the compile *and* run tests are impossible to run in a cross-compile environment.

Thus, to start the conversion process, you'll need to set the environment variables `CPP`,`CC`,`LD` and other tool aliases to the cross-compiler set of tools (probably the ones from the `NDK`) and then run `./configure`. Once this is done, then you'll need to correct the `config.h` to match your target environment. **This is your most critical and most error prone step.**

As for the `Android.mk`, it follows a format quite close to `Makefile.am` which can be easily converted into it. You can ignore the `Makefile.in` and the `Makefile`, as they are generated from the `Makefile.am`.

To take an example of [file](http://www.darwinsys.com/file/) (version 5.11), I ran configure with the following options,

```
./configure --host arm-toshiba-linux-androideabi --build x86_64-linux-gnu \
            --prefix=/data/local/ host_alias=arm-linux-androideabi \
           "CFLAGS=--sysroot=~/ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm  -Wall -Wextra" \
           "CPPFLAGS=--sysroot=~/ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm" \
            CPP=arm-linux-androideabi-cpp
```

The next step was to take the `src/Makefile.am` as below:

```
MAGIC = $(pkgdatadir)/magic
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmagic.la
include_HEADERS = magic.h

bin_PROGRAMS = file

AM_CPPFLAGS = -DMAGIC='"$(MAGIC)"'
AM_CFLAGS = $(CFLAG_VISIBILITY) @WARNINGS@

libmagic_la_SOURCES = magic.c apprentice.c softmagic.c ascmagic.c \
        encoding.c compress.c is_tar.c readelf.c print.c fsmagic.c \
        funcs.c file.h readelf.h tar.h apptype.c \
        file_opts.h elfclass.h mygetopt.h cdf.c cdf_time.c readcdf.c cdf.h
libmagic_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined -version-info 1:0:0
if MINGW
MINGWLIBS = -lgnurx -lshlwapi
else
MINGWLIBS =
endif
libmagic_la_LIBADD = $(LTLIBOBJS) $(MINGWLIBS)

file_SOURCES = file.c
file_LDADD = libmagic.la
CLEANFILES = magic.h
EXTRA_DIST = magic.h.in
HDR= $(top_srcdir)/src/magic.h.in
BUILT_SOURCES = magic.h

magic.h:        ${HDR}
        sed -e "s/X.YY/$$(echo @VERSION@ | tr -d .)/" < ${HDR} > $@
```

And create the `Android.mk` from this.

The last and most important step was to modify the `config.h` to accurately reflect the state of the target system. This will be a manual process which I cannot give a workaround for, mainly involving looking into the configure.log, looking into the headers and "invoking" Google. The fruits of this labour are available [on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1612760).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution for doing the things the other way around: building
both the external library and the Android package from standard Makefiles.

As a prerequisite, you need to install everything needed to do command line
Android development:

- A standalone toolchain, see the documentation included in the Android NDK;
- ant.

The structure of the example is: a directory for the external library
and a directory for the Android sources at the same level with a Makefile
in each directory and a top-level, recursive Makefile:

```
Makefile
mylib/
    Makefile
android/
    Makefile
```

The `mylib/Makefile` builds a static library:

```
AR=/path/to/standalone/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
CC=/path/to/standalone/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

libmylib.a: mylib.o
    $(AR) rcs libmylib.a mylib.o

mylib.o: mylib.c
    $(CC) -c mylib.c -o mylib.o
```

The `android/Makefile` is providing rules to build the Android package:

- we need a dependency to copy `mylib` when it's modified;
- we're using a `jni/ndkmake.c` file to wrap the calls to `mylib` and provide android specific stuff;
- the android package depends on the Java sources and on the shared library.

The Makefile provides two target: `release` (the default) and `debug` to build either a release package or a debug one.

```
NDK_BUILD=/path/to/ndk-build
JAVASRC=src/com/example/ndkmake/NdkMake.java

release: bin/NdkMake-release-unsigned.apk

debug: bin/NdkMake-debug.apk

bin/NdkMake-release-unsigned.apk: libs/armeabi/libndkmake.so $(JAVASRC)
ant release

bin/NdkMake-debug.apk: libs/armeabi/libndkmake.so $(JAVASRC)
ant debug

libs/armeabi/libndkmake.so: jni/ndkmake.c jni/libmylib.a
$(NDK_BUILD)

jni/libmylib.a: ../mylib/libmylib.a
cp ../mylib/libmylib.a jni/libmylib.a
```

The `Android.mk` file provides rules to include the static library in the build, as a prebuilt.
We're including headers from the `mylib` library using `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES`.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ndkmake
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndkmake.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := mylib-prebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := mylib-prebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libmylib.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ../mylib/
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Now we only need a top-level Makefile to build the two subdirectories:

```
all: libmylib package

libmylib:
    cd mylib && $(MAKE)

package:
    cd android && $(MAKE)
```

Any change to the library, to the jni sources or to the Java sources will trigger a rebuild
of the package.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Could you clarify a couple of points: 1) What do you mean by "add a build rule for the NDK stuff" what build rule? You mean the commands specified normally in the Android.mk files? 2) Where can I can find information about this standalone toolchain? Thanks!

Comment: You can find more information about standalone toolchains in the documentation shipped with the NDK, there's an online copy here: http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html As for the build rule for NDK, I mean keep the Android.mk, but run ndk-build from your Makefile (see my example)

Comment: Can I link directly to compiled c objects? For instance, if I do make on my c software right now it will output 3 `.so` files. Is there a way to make a C file with JNI methods that links to objects in the library files?

Comment: I tried that but never managed to get it working, that's why I suggest to build a static library (.a) instead and include that static library as a prebuilt.

Comment: Just thought I would let you know that I am offering a 500 rep bounty for a very detailed answer in case you want to get involved.

Comment: @thatidiotguy heh... ok, I can't give a fully detailed answer just now, but I'll do it as soon as possible. Then again, my answer is maybe not what you're looking for, as it's about running the android build process from Makefiles and not the other way around... but that does not matter, I'll post it anyway.

Comment: Using your existing code built as a static library is easier as compared to linking to it as a dynamic library as your code invariably links against glibc (whereas Android uses Bionic libc). Hence building your exiting library as a static **`.a`**, with all its dependencies statically linked within, is easier. In my personal experience, such a setup works perfectly.

Comment: @thatidiotguy ok, here it is, I updated my code to (try to) make it as complete as possible.